# JSON/AJAX and local variables in JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Working with JSON for the first time, I'm trying to call strings stored in a JSON file like this:

```
var getText = function(pat,id){ 
        $.getJSON('assets/brospeak.json',function(js){
            $('#pim1').append(js.pat.id);
        });

    }
```

So my intent is that `pat` and `id` get passed to `getText` when it's called to find the string. The problem is, the local variables in the line `$('#pim1').append(js.pat.id);` aren't getting called properly, so basically every time I call `getText` it looks for `myfile.pat.id` instead of, say, `myfile.pattern.a`. It works fine when I do just the `getJSON` part and explicitly tell it where the strings are.

The heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `js[pat][id]` instead if the property name is dynamic:

```
var getText = function(pat,id){ 
    $.getJSON('assets/brospeak.json',function(js){
        $('#pim1').append(js[pat][id]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Would that change/limit the way I structure my json file? For example having to put everything in arrays?

Comment: EDIT: Actually I have it figured out now. Thanks!